# RTC/Jazz SCM create multiple Change Sets

Tags: version-control, rtc, changeset, jazz

i have a repository workspace and i did changes on many components...
...now how can i create change sets for **all** components?

[image: unresolved changes need a change set]

as you can see above there are three components, which have unresolved changes. so i must create three change sets, one after another... and yes: all components are changed because of one bug.

i find it very hard to create so much change sets with the mouse/context menu - is there a easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [change set](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_csets.html&scope=null) is for a given component.

> A change set is a repository object that collects a related group of file, folder, and symbolic link modifications **within a component**.

In your case, that would be 3 simple mouse/content menu click, to quickly create three change sets.

However, each change set can be linked to the *same* Work Item ("related artifact"), which described your bug.

A nice trick:

**select all the Unresolved folders (multiple selection), and use the "Check-in All"

(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)**

That will create a new change set for each component.

you can use this button as well:

[image: check in all]

Comment: all you say is correct - but image i don't have to change 3 components but 30.. the list above is not complete...  then you must do 30 clicks...  and right - once you set your work item as current, all change sets that are created are associated with this selected work item...   but still: too much clicks to create change sets... sorry, that not the answer (i didn't forget your help on 'archeology', thanks again)...

Comment: @MartinFrank i have updated the answer: you can do it in one click

Comment: HA!!! you're right, you updated that answer!!! thats the help i needed, thanks thanks a lot!!! yeah, that's what i was looking for!!!

Comment: ahahaa - once you know for what you have to look you find it - thanks to you i found this button (i added it to your post)

Comment: wow - even the context menu shows that option, once you select more than one component....   narf, my question sounds so stupid now :-$